# Search MS Office files by custom properties

Tags: microsoft-office, tags, file-search

On a W2008R2 server with a File Server role we are archiving Office 2013 files, for which the users are using custom properties (as of [this link](https://goo.gl/wWYDjU)), eg.:

- `"doctype": "notification"`
- `"vectortype": "priority mail"`

I am trying to search for those files by their custom properties, but I am getting no results: I am following Microsoft rules for searching files (see [this link](http://goo.gl/83O6wK)), eg.:

- `doctype:notification`
- `vectortype:priority`

Could you please give me any hint?

Comment: it seems to be a corporate environment and therefore off-topic here. Try asking on serverfault stackexchange.

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners.